# How to extend more than one dto class in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am new to `nest.js` and have a question about it.

I want to extend more than one `Dto` to my main `dto` class, but I know it is not possible to extend more than 2 `dto` classes. Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Here is my main `dto` class:

```js
export class CarDto extends PickupLocationDto {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'Aventador', description: 'The car name' })
  readonly modelName: string;
}
```

Recently I am only able to extend it from `PickupLocationDto` class, but I want to extend one more `dto` class to this `CarDto` class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do remember `ValidationPipe` will not work with the entended classes properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since I use swagger, using `@nestjs/mapped-types` package does not show all the variables from intersected dtos. therefore, I use IntersectionType from swagger

```
import { ApiProperty, IntersectionType } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class Dto3 extends IntersectionType(
  Dto1,
  Dto2,
) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mapped-types` to do that, first you will need to install the package (`yarn add @nestjs/mapped-types`) then use `IntersectionType` just like this:

```js
import { IntersectionType } from '@nestjs/mapped-types';

export class Dto3 extends IntersectionType(
  Dto1,
  Dto2,
) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the extend keyword to extend the DTO class

```
    export class Dto3 extends Dto1 {
      public readonly dtoField: Dto2;
    }
```